# Problem with modifying an MSI database property

Tags: c#, database, windows-installer

I need to modify the `UpgradeCode` property of the `Upgrade` MSI table via C#.
This code works ok with other tables' properties, but throws an error when I'm trying to modify these.

```
using (var database = new Database(TEMPDATABASE, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))        
{
    string upgradeCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpper();
    database.Execute("Update `Upgrade` Set `Upgrade`.`UpgradeCode` = '{0}'", upgradeCode);
}
```

The error is:

> Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException: 'Function failed during execution.'

Comment: Have you checked if the database does indeed contain the  table and column property?

Comment: sure, msi database contains Upgrade table and that table also contains UpgradeCode property

Comment: It's possible your  ` are throwing it off. You could try: `Update Upgrade Set Upgrade.UpgradeCode = '{0}' ` instead

Comment: or try using $"{UpdgradeCode}" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got curious and pillaged [github.com](https://www.github.com) - and it giveth the following: [Full project](https://github.com/riha/BtsMsiLib/tree/6fafd2d2a3e2f32c51c0786ac613a5fb45765438) - just download it as a whole.

The actual code was (some unicode line feed issues in the file on [github.com](https://www.github.com), I have fixed them up here):

```
public static void UpdateUpgradeTable(this Database db, Guid upgradeCode)
{
    using (View view = db.OpenView("SELECT * FROM `Upgrade`", new object[0]))
    {
        view.Execute();
        using (Record record = view.Fetch())
        {
            record[1] = upgradeCode.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
            view.Replace(record);
        }

        db.Commit();
    }
}
```

I took the above and made the following mock-up (very ugly, but it worked):

```
using (Database db = new Database(@"C:\Test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
{
    using (View view = db.OpenView("SELECT * FROM `Upgrade`", new object[0]))
    {
        view.Execute();
        using (Record record = view.Fetch())
        {
            record[1] = "{777888DD-1111-1111-1111-222222222222}";
            record[2] = "";
            record[3] = "4.0.1";
            record[4] = "";
            record[5] = "1";
            record[6] = "";
            record[7] = "WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED";
            view.Replace(record);
        }

        db.Commit();

        using (Record record = view.Fetch())
        {
            record[1] = "{777888DD-1111-1111-1111-222222222222}";
            record[2] = "";
            record[3] = "";
            record[4] = "4.0.1";
            record[5] = "1";
            record[6] = "";
            record[7] = "WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED";
            view.Replace(record);
        }

        db.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.

Comment: Can we ask why you change the upgrade code? It should normally not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The [SDK doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/sql-syntax) says:

> UPDATE queries only work on nonprimary key columns.

`UpgradeCode` is the primary key for the `Upgrade` table.