# Update a property in msi created with Wix toolset

Tags: c#, .net-core, wix, windows-installer

I have created msi using Wix toolset for worker service as window service. In setup project ,i have added a property in product.wxs file.

`<Property Id="DF_PORT" Value="8080"/>`

How can i update the value of 'DF_PORT' property using .net core. i have tried c# code below.But not working.
Reference: [Can't rename MSI afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542919/cant-rename-msi-afterwards)

```
private string SetMsiProperty(string msiFilePath, string property, string value)
        {
            string retVal = string.Empty;

            // Create an Installer instance  
            WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)new Installer();

            // Open the msi file for reading  
            // 0 - Read, 1 - Read/Write  
            Database db = installer.OpenDatabase(msiFilePath, WindowsInstaller.MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact); //// Open the MSI database in the input file 

            // Fetch the requested property  
            string sql = String.Format("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='{0}'", property);

            View view = db.OpenView(sql); //View vw = db.OpenView(@"SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property` = 'ProductVersion'");            
            view.Execute(null);

            // Read in the fetched record  
            Record record = view.Fetch();
            if (record != null)
            {
                record.set_StringData(1, value);


            }

            view.Modify(MsiViewModify.msiViewModifyReplace, record);
            view.Close();
            db.Commit();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(record);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(view);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(db);

            return retVal;
        }
```

Comment: If can the property value from command line, when invoking the installer

Comment: Is there  any way  to update msi property using .net core?

Comment: A couple of links: [Modify MSI property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778570/129130), [TemporaryFilesExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225970/129130), [Uninstall MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280957/129130). This is not a custom action - is it? In other words an action embedded in the MSI.