# How to add a new row to Property table of msi file using c#/cmd

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I need to add a new row in the msi file database i.e. I need to add a new row in Property table.
ServerUrl = "www.google.com". I have tried using orca and I was able to do it. But this is a manual process. I need to do it via code.

1. Without starting the installer.
2. Without using orca

How can I achieve this in c#? I tried to use the command line options but it starts the installer. I need to edit the table without starting the installer in the existing msi file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been a while since I looked at this, I'll just point you to two previous answers.

***Important!***: You should always avoid post-processing the MSI if you can. You can create an MST (transform) to add this to the MSI during installation or set it as a property at the command line. See this old answer: [Transforms and PUBLIC PROPERTIES: heavy-weight and light-weight customization of MSI installers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58232330/129130) and [from section "Customizing Silent Install" onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455886/129130).

---

***VBScript***: There is a VBScript **`WiRunSQL.vbs`** - which is part of the Windows SDK - just search your SDK folder if you have Visual Studio installed.

You can use this and a batch file to post-process an MSI ([sample here](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/tree/master/Post%20Process%20MSI)):

```
cscript.exe "%~dp0"\WiRunSQL.vbs "MySetup.msi" "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('MYPROPERTY', 'PropertyValue')"  
pause
```

There is [a previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103086/129130) on how to change things in the ControlCondition table.

---

***C#***: There is also [some C# code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778570/129130) you can test. Not that well tested, and not the greatest code overall, but have a look?

Alternatively try [this source](https://github.com/pavelDruzhinin/introduction-c-sharp/blob/9c6570b62805b66d989b61b888113f91b8280950/language%20features/TestVersion/TestVersion/PropertyTable.cs#L39). You need to know what DTF is for this source. [What is DTF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061606/129130)? DTF is included in the code by this reference: **`using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;`**

Briefly inlined:

```
public static void Set(string msi, string name, string value)
{
   using (Database db = new Database(msi, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
   {
      db.Execute("UPDATE `Property` SET `Value` = '{0}' WHERE `Property` = '{1}'", value, name);
   }
}
```

---

***Some Links***:

- [Currupted file in non-english locale (encoding problem?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220922/currupted-file-in-non-english-locale-encoding-problem/57225970#57225970)
- [cx_freeze bdist_msi: create registry entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656310/cx-freeze-bdist-msi-create-registry-entries/51758146#51758146)
- [MSI code from github](https://github.com/jixingchun/WixSample/blob/e3636d876659bcd42587d04e2c4dac6827f460c0/WixSampleProject/ConsoleApp1/MSIEditor.cs#L85)
- [Features, Transforms, Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861)
- [How to tag or customize the a binary (for example of an installer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453205/how-to-tag-or-customize-the-a-binary-for-example-of-an-installer/49589427#49589427)

Comment: If it worked you can set the answer accepted. What solution did you end up with?

Comment: C# solution, sure let me set the answer accepted

Comment: Hi @stein if possible can you please help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556798/wix-customaction-gives-error-2896-when-used-with-publish-event-doaction

Comment: A bit busy right now, but please check if this project helps: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXOpenLogFile and [have a read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850388/129130) and follow the links please. There are further WiX examples at the top level of that Github repository.